# Programmers Community Blog 2.0

Tags: discussion, blog

### For those of you that still don't know...

Programmers.SE has an [official community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/). The content there is pretty awesome, and [some](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/20-controversial-programming-opinions/) [posts](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/fix-price-vs-time-and-material-contracts/) have gotten crazy amounts of traffic. It's really nice to see the community come together and write for the blog.

The problem is, the blog has really died down in terms of activity. We haven't had a new post since November. We haven't had a strict posting schedule (besides November, our last post was in July). A lot of the people that participated in the blog at its inception are no longer active. The decline of the community blog is due to a lot of different things. We want to fix them.

### Active Contributors

The first thing a community blog needs is active contributors.

From asking in [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), it seems that there is still active interest in the blog, but things need to change. There needs to be much more organization behind the scenes in order to have any success in running this project. To do this, we need two things:

1. **Writing Process.** When we first started the blog, you really could do
   anything. One person would write the post, edit the post, proofread
   the post, etc.. There really was no organization as far as who did
   what. In the new system (we'll call it Blog 2.0), one person will
   not be doing everything. Everybody will still be able to write
   posts, but it won't be a personal endeavor. There might be several
   people contributing to writing one post. There will be designated
   editors/proofreaders who will fix grammar and formatting and give
   feedback. All posts will go through an outlined process and meet a
   certain criteria (which will be specified based on community ideas)
   in order to get published. We tried doing this with the blog before.
   We had editors, including me, who would attempt to go through and
   edit posts. Unfortunately, I was a terrible editor. Not only am I
   not the best writer, but it is difficult to fix things that you know
   little about. Blog 2.0 will implement a new writing process, in
   order to streamline our approach to publishing.
2. **Activity.** Participating in the community blog should not be an extra
   job. You shouldn't feel stressed out to finish a post or to get
   something published on time. Life already has enough deadlines. That
   said, we still need people to be consistently active with their
   participation. If you're on board to finish a post by a certain
   date, we need it done by that date. Basically, set your own
   deadlines, but stick to them

Again, blog participation is supposed to be just as enjoyable as using the main site. It's another way to create content, without being restricted by the typical Q&A format. If you're interested in contributing to the blog, just leave a comment or contact me on The Whiteboard. We need as many contributors as possible.

### Content

Now, on to the meat of the blog.

The actual content getting published by the blog has been pretty good, but it is not reaching its full potential. The blog should consist of a few things things:

- **Announcements.** The blog should be a place where we can voice what is going on with Programmers.SE. We've done posts like this before,
  but the platform hasn't been used to its full potential.
- **Posts About Programming.** That's what most of the posts have been so
  far, and we still want more of these.
- **Posts that were "Not Constructive".** This is a gold mine. The [last
  time](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/20-controversial-programming-opinions/) this was done, it became our most popular post. Basically, good
  questions that didn't fit the Stack Exchange format, and turn them
  into blog posts.
- **Meta Posts.** There has been a bit of interest in this lately.
  Basically, create explanations of frequently asked questions or
  common close reasons and post them to the blog, in order to link to
  them whenever the issue arises.

The possibilities are endless when it comes to content. Those were just ideas that have come up, but if you have more, feel free to tell us!

### Wanna Contribute? Have Ideas?

If you'd like to contribute to the blog, or have any ideas regarding the blog, feel free to leave a comment, answer, or ping me in chat. The Programmers Community Blog is an awesome platform, so don't let it go to waste.

---

Remember that this entire post is just a conjunction of fluid ideas. They can be completely changed if the community has better ideas. ***We are happily welcoming any feedback, criticism, and ideas that you have or would like to develop.***

Comment: Just a thought... if you make blog posts from older "Not Constructive" posts, you may want to make it very clear that the type of content is not welcome on the main site. Which makes me think it might be a bad idea to include that sort of stuff in a blog for the site in the first place.

Comment: @Rachel I see what you're saying, and I also believe that a friendly reminder would be needed. That said, when we have done this in the past (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong) there wasn't any sort of influx in the number of questions asked, whether it be constructive or not constructive.

Comment: @WorldEngineer Would you mind unfreezing the Blog Chatroom?

Comment: How is a collaborative writing process supposed to work?  Even on the main site, where editing is essentially open, the process of writing questions and answers is not really collaborative.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The idea is not necessarily a real-time collaboration writing process, but that you won't be the only one working on a post. Let's say the post was comparing C# and Java. One person may be writing about speed while somebody else is writing about job availability. Another person would take all of the parts and piece them together, making the necessary edits to create a solid blog post. Basically, each post will be a community effort, but not everybody will necessarily be writing every part of the post. Again, these are just preliminary ideas that can be improved by the community.

Answer (score 4):

I want to get back Involved, writing again, but wont be till the July time frame.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, and that's totally okay.

Comment: anyone's still on with this?