# Programmers Community Blog 3.0

Tags: discussion, blog

Any one have interest in getting our blog back up? We haven't published anything in over 3 years.

No need to retype all this - See: [Programmers Community Blog 2.0](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/programmers-community-blog-2-0)

We still have our Trello board loaded with post ideas....

Comment: If you did this it wouldn't be hosted by SE. They've recently shut down all the community blogs. Most just exist as static pages now.

Comment: @ChrisF  That's I'll cover the hosting cost. We still have access to Wordpress.

Comment: Cool. Just so everybody knows what the score is. I do believe that you can get branding assets from SE though.

Comment: @ChrisF http://stackexchange.com/blogs seems to have some recent post from SIFI & LaTeX .. where does it say it was shut down?

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/blog-overflow-is-ending-what-should-we-do-with-the-existing-blog-posts

Comment: How is this going to differ and differentiate itself from [the existing unofficial chat community blog](http://the-whiteboard.github.io/)?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I thought that one was owned by MichaelT.  He doesn't even have an account here anymore.

Comment: @Morons, the SF&F (http://thesffblog.com/about/) and LaTex blogs (http://tex-talk.net/about/) are actually on separate sites from the StackExchange network. It looks like SE is still willing to link to new blog posts on those sites though: http://stackexchange.com/blogs

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the latest published article is by him, but the latest was just 21 hours ago by shagie.

Comment: As far as I know, "The Whiteboard" blog is deliberately not tied to this site, and it was created after "we" stopped participating actively here (these days I only show up for HNQs and hot meta questions). So if those of you who are still here want a proper blog that is intended to represent this site, then that's what'll differentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the original writers on board. Personally I think it's a good and generous idea to build the blog.

I'm ready to help again, so count me in.

Comment: Apparently its not even an option, see : http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/blog-overflow-is-ending-what-should-we-do-with-the-existing-blog-posts#comment26401_8323

Comment: @Morons You can copy the pages from the Blog Overflow blog and republish the articles when you start a new Software Engineering blog. You don't need a data dump, even though it would be convenient. Just start the new blog, we can later figure out how to make it the “official” Software Engineering community blog.

Comment: @amon: I'm not sure it could be an "official" page or not. We could still write about it. The content in Software Engineer is quite good: having a blog which, for example, just to go in-depth for high-scored/hot questions seems interesting.

Comment: @Morons another promising idea popped up recently: [Proposal for Leveraging the Main Site for “Blog Posts” and Other Extended Content](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8386/31260)